# Cakephp 3 : How loadModel function defines globally?

Tags: cakephp, orm, model, cakephp-3.0

I am new to cakephp3.I read http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ and start developing small application using cakephp3.
I am using UserMastersController and I want to save and get data from person_masters table.For that each time I am using loadModel() or TabelRegistry::get(); methods in each function.

```
$this->loadModel('PersonMasters');
```

So, how can I define globally other models in cakephp3, so I should not define each time in each function ?

Comment: Do you want to load this model for every controller ?

Comment: not for every controller ..but i want to define Model globally for one particular controller...because in my UserMasterController there are different function that use person_masters database table..so each time i write this line:$this->loadModel('PersonMasters'); in each functions..so how can i define globally?

Comment: Where you have tried this code ?May you provide your find method please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### use the beforeFilter

> I am using loadModel() or TabelRegistry::get(); methods in each function.

The simplest solution is to [define the beforeFilter method](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks) in the relevant controller:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->loadModel('PersonMasters');
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
}

public function example()
{
    $this->PersonMasters->find(); // no error
}
```

If you prefer, you could instead change the name of the default table class, which [is set automatically to the name of the controller class](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Controller/Controller.php#L255-L256) - [if it isn't already set](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Datasource/ModelAwareTrait.php#L49-L62). This is how the convention of "FoosController will use the Foos table class" is implemented. I.e. this would also work:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    $this->modelClass = 'PersonMasters';
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
}

public function example()
{
    $this->PersonMasters->find(); // no error
}
```

Though that's more indirect and probably more confusing for future readers of the code (e.g. you, next year, next week - or tomorrow =)).